# Excel: Set background color of cell and text color with rgb

Tags: vba, excel, rgb, background-color, textcolor

I'm write a program that change font and background color due to user request. after received **backgroundColorData** and **textColorData** 
i did like to change colors due to user request but i feel there is a better way to make it then what i choose to do (my code is maybe repeating itself)
other issue i didn't find an answer for is how to make textColor/backgroundColor more "red" or more "blue"

```
  Select Case backgroundColorData
        Case Is = "Black"
            Selection.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
        Case Is = "Red"
             Selection.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        Case Is = "Blue"
             Selection.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 255)
        Case Is = "White"
             Selection.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
  End Select


    Select Case textColorData
        Case Is = "Black"
            Selection.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
        Case Is = "Red"
             Selection.Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        Case Is = "Blue"
             Selection.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 255)
        Case Is = "White"
             Selection.Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
     End Select
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, David. While any new user is always welcome it seems to me that the post might be misplaced here. If you are striving to optimize code then you should rather post your question here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ This is where you'd post **working** code which merely requires optimization. In respect to your other question: searching for a color which is "redder" than red you might want to experiment with the colors offered by windows (16+ million colors) and if that still doesn't suffice then you might want to invest in a new monitor.

Comment: Hey @Ralph, thanks for your comment i'm new in this site and i didn't hared about the site you mention but be sure i will use it next time i would ask advice for "optimize code". about my second question i think I didn't explain well my question:
when a user ask me to make a cell background more Blue or Red (etc..) is there any option with RGB to do it Relatively to the current color? for example something like that: .Font.Color = Rgb(+100 red) ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Sub tester()

    Dim backgroundColorData As String, textColorData As String

    backgroundColorData = "Blue"
    textColorData = "White"

    With Selection
        .Interior.Color = NameToRgb(backgroundColorData)
        .Font.Color = NameToRgb(textColorData)
    End With

End Sub

'map a color name to an rgb value
Function NameToRgb(sName As String) As Long
    Dim arrNames, arrRGB, v
    arrNames = Array("black", "red", "blue", "white")
    arrRGB = Array(RGB(0, 0, 0), RGB(255, 0, 0), _
                   RGB(0, 0, 255), RGB(255, 255, 255))

    v = Application.Match(LCase(sName), arrNames, 0)
    If Not IsError(v) Then
        NameToRgb = arrRGB(v - 1)
    Else
        NameToRgb = vbBlack 'default...
    End If
End Function
```

If you want to find an exact color value for something "more red", set the background in a cell to the color you want, select the cell, then in the VB editor Immediate pane type:

```
? Selection.Interior.Color
```

Copy the number and use that in place of your RGB() value

**EDIT**: OK now I see what you mean about making a cell more red...

```
Sub MoreRed(c As Range)
    Dim R As Long, G As Long, B As Long, clr As Long

    clr = c.Interior.Color
    B = clr \ 65536
    G = (clr - B * 65536) \ 256
    R = clr - B * 65536 - G * 256
    'Debug.Print R, G, B
    R = Application.Min(R + 20, 255) 'more red...
    c.Interior.Color = RGB(R, G, B)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @TimWilliams , this is very helpful! about your second part of your answer, maybe I should ask again (more clearly) when a user ask me to make a cell background more Blue or Red (etc..) is there any option with RGB to do it Relatively to the current color? for example something like that: .Font.Color = Rgb(+100 red) ??

Comment: Well, you can certainly try adjusting the "red" agument (the first parameter in the RGB call).  RGB(100, 0, 255) is "more red" than RGB(0, 0, 255)

Comment: OK, but your answer is assume that the color in current cell will be RGB(0, 0, 255), and i don't know that, this is the reason i'm searching for a way to do it relatively to the color is already there...

Comment: Thanks @Tim , I would never could get that by myself your answer really helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to stack overflow.

You can do it with a single function like this-

```
Function setColor(SelectionData As String) 

 Select Case SelectionData As String
      Dim returnValue As String  
        Case Is = "Black"
            returnValue  = RGB(0, 0, 0)
        Case Is = "Red"
             returnValue  = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        Case Is = "Blue"
             returnValue  = RGB(0, 0, 255)
        Case Is = "White"
             returnValue  = RGB(255, 255, 255)
     End Select  
return returnValue  
End Function
```

And then just call your function like this-

```
setColor(textColorData)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is also very helpful!